# Calculating $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{10^x - 2^x - 5^x + 1}{x \cdot \tan x}$

Tags: limits, education

I am trying to solve this limit without using Taylor expansions to explain it to a secondary school student

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{10^x - 2^x - 5^x + 1}{x \cdot \tan x}.$$

Comment: the developpement limité

Comment: bachelor?${}{}$

Comment: I mean a student who studying in secondery school

Comment: @TMM sounds like french

Comment: yes u can call it Taylor expansion

Comment: okay. taylor expansion. that makes sense.

Comment: You can use two formulae:$$lim_{x\to0}\frac{a^x-1}{x}=loga$$ and $$lim_{x\to0} \frac{tanx}{x}=1$$

Comment: Factor top as $(5^x-1)(2^x-1)$. Let $x$ take care of one of them and $\tan x$ of the other.

Comment: ok that makes the limit equals to log2*log5 , thanks

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{(2^x-1)(5^x-1)}{x\tan(x)}$$

$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{x(2^x-1)(5^x-1)}{x\cdot x\tan(x)}$$

$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{(2^x-1)(5^x-1)}{x^2}\cdot\color{red}{\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{\tan(x)}}$$

The highlighted limit is $1$.

$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{(2^x-1)(5^x-1)}{x^2}$$

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2^x-1}{x}\cdot\lim_{x\to0}\frac{5^x-1}{x}$$

Which may be individually calculated using L'hospital's rule.

Comment: I don't think l'Hopital's rule is known to secondary school students. (I don't remember seeing it back then anyway.)

Comment: yeah I edited the post, in my country it is known for a secondery student, thanks a lot

Comment: @TMM what would "secondary school" mean in your country? In India it probably refers to ages ~16-18, and I currently am at that, and we saw this quite quickly, within the first week of calculus I think.

Comment: Can we then take $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{a^x-1}{x}=\log(a)$ for granted? Apart from that I am blank.

Comment: u can consider a changement of variable, e^x*log(a)-1= 1/t, t-> infinity as x->0

Comment: @user2161721 that would still be taking $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}{x} = 1$ for granted.